# Dojo: how to get attr of dynamically created element

Tags: dojo, onclick, click

Seems like I cannot catch the click event on dynamically created elements with dojo.

This is how I create the list of links:

```
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
     console.log( items[i].getAttribute("jid") )                    
     dojo.place("<li><a href='#' id='temp'>" + items[i].getAttribute("firstname") + "</a></li>", "log");
}

on( '#temp' ).on( 'click', function( evt ) {
    console.log( "click" );
});
```

Unfortunately the event doesn't get registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here are the docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/on.html) for `dojo/on`; you need to pass an element, an event type, and a handler. It looks like you will need `dojo/query` where you're trying to use `on` the first time; [docs are here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/query.html).

It looks like you want to set up a click handler for each of your dynamically created elements. So, `query` for those elements and set up a click handler on each of them.

I changed your `id` to a `class` because it's not a good idea to have multiple elements with the same id, but the concept is the same. Instead of your `on` chain above, something like this would work:

```
query('.temp').forEach(function(t) {
    on(t, 'click', function(evt) {
        console.log('click', evt);
    });
});
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/FGSJu/) with some dummy items; presumably your items are slightly different.